# Bounded frontier_exploration using code rather than rviz point tool

Tags: ros, exploration, frontier-exploration, actionlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The code below should define a polyStamped name "boundary" that includes points p1, p2, p3, and p4.  Here is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
 ros::init(argc, argv, "send_exploration_goal");

 Cient client("explore_server", true);
 client.waitForServer();
 frontier_exploration::ExploreTaskGoal goal;

 geometry_msgs::PolygonStamped boundary;
 geometry_msgs::Point32 p1, p2, p3, p4;

 p1.x = 2.0; p1.y = 2.0; p1.z = 0.0;
 p2.x = 2.0; p2.y = -2.0; p2.z = 0.0;
 p3.x = -2.0; p3.y = -2.0; p3.z = 0.0;
 p4.x = -2.0; p4.y = 2.0; p4.z = 0.0;

 // defining the boundary polygon here
 boundary.header.seq = 1;
 boundary.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
 boundary.header.frame_id = "map";
 boundary.polygon.points.reserve(4);
 boundary.polygon.points[0] = p1;
 boundary.polygon.points[1] = p2;
 boundary.polygon.points[2] = p3;
 boundary.polygon.points[3] = p4;

 // defining the explore center here
 geometry_msgs::PointStamped start_point;
 start_point.point.x = 0.0; start_point.point.y = 0.0; start_point.point.z = 0.0;

 goal.explore_center = start_point;
 goal.explore_boundary = boundary;
 client.sendGoal(goal);
}
```

When I "cout << boundary", the polygon.points[] shows up empty.  How do you correctly define the points of a polygon Stamped?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230456/bounded-frontier_exploration-using-code-rather-than-rviz-point-tool/) by [pgigioli](https://answers.ros.org/users/26279/pgigioli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 354 on 2016-03-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Figured it out.  Define the polygon like this:

```
boundary.polygon.points.push_back(p1);
boundary.polygon.points.push_back(p2);
boundary.polygon.points.push_back(p3);
boundary.polygon.points.push_back(p4);
boundary.polygon.points.push_back(p5);
```

---

Originally posted by [pgigioli](https://answers.ros.org/users/26279/pgigioli/) with karma: 354 on 2016-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0